# Saving an image URL into variables.scss

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I'm trying to put an image into the variables.scss so I can call them relatively easier than writing the whole path down. The goal is that I can call --companyname-logo into a (html element preferred) or in css and that my image from /assets/icon/logo.png gets called and shown.

**variables.scss**

```
$assetPath: "/assets/";
:root{
  --company-logo: url(#{$assetPath}icon/logo.png);
}
```

I also tried to put the $assetPath variable into the :root brackets but changed nothing for me.

**html** (I'll list up on each line what I tried)

```
<ion-img src="--company-logo"> </ion-img>
<ion-img [src*="#{--company-logo}"]> </ion-img>
<ion-img [src]=--company-logo></ion-img>
<ion-img [src]="--company-logo"></ion-img>
```

Any sugesstions?

Comment: Hello, first of all you are confusing **css custom properties** and **sass variables**. Then, you can't use a css custom property in your html like this.

Comment: Oh okay do you know a clean code way to call my logo from a higher level so I don't have to initialize the path every time?

Comment: You could use a custom element, something like `<i class="my-logo"></i>` and a class specifying a size and a background-image, but I wouldn't do it for a logo, I would only use it for a decorative element.